# adding the dll into project without using Bin folder WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dll

I have one dll into my project and I need to add it in my project and give the reference in a xaml window but the problem is when I install the setup.exe in my system then that dll is showing in Program files in the system that I dont want. But if I don't add the dll in bin folder then it is showing the error. SO is there any way to add the dll in a particular way so that I dont get any error and it will not show into the program files.

The reference I am adding is:

> xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"

Comment: If you are adding a reference to a dll (physical file) then simply go to reference > your dll and on the properties set copy to local = `false`.

Comment: Though, it is working and dll is not showing in the program file but My setup is getting crashed. This is the big problem

Comment: That is the purpose of copy to local = `true`. It ensures that your application has a copy of your dependency file.

Comment: _give the reference in a xaml window_ is not very clear. Do you also add it to the References in your project?

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Yes,obivously